# Why does $αA^{−1} + (1 −α)B^{−1}\succeq (αA + (1 − α)B)^{−1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B \in M_n$ be positive definite and let $α\in (0, 1)$.
 Why does $αA^{−1} + (1 −α)B^{−1}\succeq (αA + (1 − α)B)^{−1}$?

Comment: Like the question, but just for clarity could you define what $\succeq$ means?